# call failed: RPC: Can't encode arguments

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, rpc

I'm creating a very simple RPC. Client sends an image in a char array. Server simply takes every other pixel in image, stores it in an array and then sends back. 
It is pretty naive but I'm new to this and I'm practicing. 
For the client part, most of the code is auto generated. I have added my code after DEBUG comment. Not sure what the problem might be because when I run make command, it runs perfectly fine
Client

```
#include "compress.h"


void
compress_1(char *host)
{
    CLIENT *clnt;
    char * *result_1;
    image  add_1_arg;

#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt = clnt_create (host, COMPRESS, COMPRESS_VERS, "udp");
    if (clnt == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror (host);
        exit (1);
    }
#endif  /* DEBUG */

    result_1 = add_1(&add_1_arg, clnt);
    if (result_1 == (char **) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }

   printf("%s", result_1);


#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt_destroy (clnt);
#endif   /* DEBUG */
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *host;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("usage: %s server_host\n", argv[0]);
        exit (1);
    }
    host = argv[1];
    compress_1 (host);
exit (0);
}
```

Server

```
#include "compress.h"

char **
add_1_svc(image *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static char * result=malloc (sizeof(argp->buffer));;




    return &result;
}
```

compress.x

```
struct image{
      char buffer[69999];
};

program COMPRESS{

          version COMPRESS_VERS{
               string add(image)=1;

}=1;
}=0x23451112;
```

I keep getting this error when I run my client

```
call failed: RPC: Can't encode arguments
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Edit:
I have edited the question above. Now I am simply sending a string. But on the client side result_1 is printing (null). I think it has something to do with malloc or pointer to pointer return. I can't figure out.

Comment: you write into the uninitialized result pointer inside server

Comment: @ChrisB how? using malloc?

Comment: yes. you need to allocate a buffer for the result.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be using a static buffer! What if there are two clients running? What OS/RPC infrastructure are you targeting?

Comment: @ChrisB tried this char * result=malloc (sizeof(argp->buffer));. Not working still

Comment: The answer to your question is OS/RPC dependent unless you are using some kind of framework to hide those details. In any case, if you simply `malloc` a buffer and hand it off to the transport layer, you are likely to create a memory leak. RPC frameworks and related OS specific API's, generally provide an allocator for you to use in this specific situation.

Comment: @jwdonahue I simply installed RPCbind and OS is ubuntu 14

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  there is no file named 'compress.h' (and what is 'compress.x' expected to de? ) Note: Header files should not contain function bodes, Generally, only  function prototypes and data formats.  Note:  there is a LOT of missing code.